# Custom modules using Spotify require()

Tags: spotify

The [Spotify documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/global.html#require) states that you can define custom modules, but I can't find any documentation on how to write them. I'm assuming it's some combination of changes in the manifest.json file and writing an AMD module (like with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/))

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own modules using the following approach.

Create a module that exports certain variables or functions that you want to make accessible. For instance, you can have a `js/myModule.js` file exporting an `init` function:

```js
exports.init = function() { ... };
```

Then, in another file, you can require it using the `require` function that you normally use to include modules from the Spotify API:

```js
var sp = getSpotifyApi(),
    models = sp.require("$api/models"),
    views = sp.require("$api/views"),
    myModule = sp.require("/js/myModule");

myModule.init();
```

Comment: Does this work with the Preview API and can I define dependencies?

Comment: Yes, it works in a similar way. In your module you export your functions assigning them to the exports variable, but you require them  using `require(["$api/models", "$api/views", "/js/myModule"], function (models, views, myModule) { ... });`
Have into account that this may change once the new API is finally released.

Comment: Inside a module can I set dependencies? This would mean a require() could call a module that has its own require().

Comment: Yes, you can. Each module can have its own dependencies (retrieved using `require`) and export its exposed functions using the `exports` variable.

Comment: Is there an example of how I would tie that all together? I believe the require method has a callback, so how would that work with an exports variable?